# Will OpenGL ES 1.1 become obsolete in iOS?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader, vector-graphics

I am at a crossroads between using OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0 for iPhone development. I plan on creating 2D applications and simple 3D applications. In the interest of simplicity, should I use 1.1? Or will this be discontinued at some point in iOS? I would like to know if the shaders in 2.0 are significantly more beneficial in making simple programs than the shaders in 1.1. Please tell me the advantages of each. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the definitive reason the use 2.0 starting out is complex effects, 2.0 is a wild card in this matter, shaders are little bits of software that run inside the graphics card (ok, not always true) and have the ability to affect individual pixels at run time. In 1.1 there's a lot you can do, but most of the time you're affecting all the pixels in the texture, to affect individual pixels, you have to combine textures, and the after a while there's just stuff you can't do in 1.1.

Now if you don't need complex effects, you can start and use 1.1, but let me show you your journey:

In the beginning 1.1 will be easier, glTranslatef, glRotatef, glScalef, etc do save you time and allow you to start manipulating objects easily.

But has you progress and start to do more complex things, you learn about matrix manipulations, say there's a routine that's a bit slow because you're doing a lot of tranlastes, rotates, etc. So you read up on the subject and learn you can combine all those operations into one matrix, so you start doing your own matrix calc funcs and start to use glMultMatrixf more, after a while it's just easier to always glMultMatrixf, because you can latter add stuff without having to rewrite code.

At this point you have no reason to use 1.1, going from glMultMatrixf to 2.0 is a very small step, and you get that whole new world from the shaders.

So, if you don't need big effects and are itching to go, alright use 1.1.
Anything else just go direct to 2.0.

**Disclaimer**
Yes this is a simplification, but a journey i've made myself.

Answer (score 1):

2.0 has a programmable pipeline

This seems like not very much information (as when i first started i was like "uh ok?") but it really means a lot.

In allowing you to take control of the transformations of vertices

Now in the smaller things I have done (3d) the transformations could easily be managed by 1.1 automatically, but it is cool to have total control over them in 2.0

If you're learning opengles on the idevices i suggest making programs at first that support both 1.1 and 2.0 so you can get even more experience and understanding into opengles

If you need full control over the vertices then 2.0 is the way to go, otherwise 1.1 should be fine